# Powershell 2 Files Execution Script

Tags: powershell

I'm tryng to run the following ps1 script

```html
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://server/file1.exe','file1.exe');Start-Process 'file1.exe'
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://server/file2.exe','file2.exe');Start-Process 'file2.exe'
```

But I'm only being able to download the file1.exe without it to run

How can I do download and execute file1.exe and after that file2.exe

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the Full path and filename for the downloaded files.

```
$file1 = 'D:\Test\file1.exe'
$file2 = 'D:\Test\file2.exe'

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://server/file1.exe',$file1)
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://server/file2.exe',$file2)
$webClient.Dispose()
```

Then to run the executables one after the other:

```
$process = Start-Process $file1 -PassThru 
$process.WaitForExit()

$process = Start-Process $file2 -PassThru 
$process.WaitForExit()
```